# Presto possible table format values

Tags: presto

According [to the docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/create-table.html), when creating a table in Presto

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  orderkey bigint,
  orderstatus varchar,
  totalprice double,
  orderdate date
)
WITH (format = 'ORC')
```

you can specify `format = 'xxx'`. Apart from 'ORC' I know there is a `TEXTFILE`. I am curious what other options for the `format` are there? And is there a reason why you shouldn't use the 'ORC' (I suppose it's the default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Hive connector, supported file formats are listed in the [Hive connector documentation](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#supported-file-types).

ORC is *not* default (`hive.storage-format` connector configuration property governs default format when not specified in `CREATE TABLE` and that setting currently defaults to `RCBINARY`), though it's generally recommendable choice.